# Return multiple values from ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, return

I have method in C#, I have to return all values from ArrayList.

```
public string vyhledavaniOS()
        {
                foreach (Vozidlo voz in nabídka)
                {
                    if (voz is OsobníVůz)
                        return (voz.TypVozidla() + ": SPZ: " + voz.JakaSPZ + ", Značka: " + voz.JakaZnacka + ", Barva: " + voz.JakaBarva);
                }
        }
```

This code returns only one value, is there any way, how to return all values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to change the method to return an array of strings instead of only one string value. Something like this:

```
public List<string> vyhledavaniOS()
{
    List<string> listToReturn = new List<string>();

    foreach (Vozidlo voz in nabídka)
    {
        if (voz is OsobníVuz)
            listToReturn.Add((voz.TypVozidla() + ": SPZ: " + voz.JakaSPZ + ", Znacka: " + voz.JakaZnacka + ", Barva: " + voz.JakaBarva));
    }

    return listToReturn;
}
```

Comment: What platform is this? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: Then I HIGHLY recommend that you start learning the `MVVM` pattern for WPF applications. [Here's a very good quick-start tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial). Alternatively, after you call the `vyhledavaniOS()` method, you can add the results to the `ListBox` using something like `myListBox.Items.Add()`.

Comment: I have 
LB_vypis.Items.Add(nb.vyhledavaniOS())  
but that does not show the values.

Comment: `Items.Add()` takes one item, but your method returns a list. You have to use a loop to add each item to the list. Something like: `foreach(string item in nb.vyhledavaniOS()) { LB_vypis.Items.Add(item); }`